# platform.system() not working on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I've just installed WinPython (32 bit) on my Windows machine and am trying to run code which otherwise works on my remote linux machine. The code makes use of Python's `platform` library. The problem is when I run my code, I get an error where my code is trying to make use of `platform` library's function `platform.system()`

`platform.system()` should return a string like `Linux`, `Windows`, etc., but on my Windows system, a call to `platform.system()` gets the following result:

```
>>> import platform
>>> print platform.system()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'system'
```

Any ideas why the above is happening ? The  WinPython I have is based on the latest Python 2.7 (I think 2.7.10), and Python 2.7 DOES have a `platform.system()` method as mentioned here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html

So I'm not sure what's the problem. Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you name a file `platform.py`?

Comment: Or a file or directory named `platform`?

Comment: or a directory named `platform` that has an `__init__.py` ?

Comment: I didn't name or rename anything as playtform.py or anything similar. I have located the platform.py file in the "Lib" folder which does have a definition for the `system()` function. For some reason though, it's not being called

Comment: What is shown when you enter `import platform` and then just `platform` in the interpreter?

Comment: `>>> import platform
>>> platform
<module 'platform' from 'platform.pyc'>`

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to split lines in comments. I hope you can make out the commands I typed (`import platform` and then `platform`) and their response: `<module 'platform' from 'platform.pyc'>`

Comment: That sounds like you named a file `platform.py` and then deleted it, but there's still a compiled version `platform.pyc` hanging around. Delete `platform.pyc`.

Comment: Then, there is at least a platform.pyc in the current directory.

Comment: I tried searching the whole WinPython directory for files with names `platform.py` or `platform.pyc`. I found out that WinPython had installed one other package which used these names, called `bokeh`. I've uninstalled that package from WinPython's control panel, and now there are no other files with names `platform.py` or `platform.pyc` in the WinPython directory. However even now, I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

This has been tried on winpython2.7.10 32 bit:

`import platform;platform.system()`

[image]

Comment: Same here on python 3.5 windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

It definitely looks like the `platform` you get when you `import platform` is not the built-in module. You should find out what exactly is imported.

I believe the folowing should print out find all candidates. What does it print in your case?

```
import os, sys
for p in sys.path:
    try:
        for fn in (os.listdir(p or '.')):
            if 'platform' in fn.lower():
                print os.path.join(p, fn)
    except OSError:
        print ':skipped', p
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the code, it said that "platform" was a string, which it wasn't. I just did `import platform as platform_module` instead of `import platform` and then replaced "platform" with "platform_module" and it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35003334)